# Remove duplicate images

Tags: command-line, scripts

I have original image is img.jpg.

How can I remove duplicate images which are img.jpg1, img.jpg2, img.jpg3.
I want to keep the image which have .jpg extension.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the `find` command with `-regex` and `-exec` flags. In this particular example, `-exec` simply takes all the dupe images and moves them to trash bin, so you still can recover any of them if you choose so. You can later use `rm` command, or clean trash through GUI

```
testerdir:$ ls
img.jpg  img.jpg1  img.jpg2  img.jpg3

testerdir:$ find  . -regex ".*\.jpg[1-9]+" -print -exec mv -t $HOME/.local/share/Trash/ {} +                                 
./img.jpg1
./img.jpg3
./img.jpg2

testerdir:$ ls $HOME/.local/share/Trash                                                                                   
expunged/  files/  img.jpg1  img.jpg2  img.jpg3  info/

testerdir:$ ls
img.jpg
```

Comment: `-regex ".*\.jpg[1-9]+"` ... perhaps

Comment: Yes that will be more accurate

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
How can I directly remove the file without moving to trash.

Comment: @Neo you can replace the `mv  -t $HOME/.local/share/Trash {} +` part with  `rm {} +`

Comment: @Neo You're very welcome. Please mark my answer as accepted if you found that it solved your question ( by clicking grey check mark next to up down arrows )

Comment: Little suggestion, `-regex "\.jpg[1-9]+$"` to exclude stuff like "foo.jpg1.bar"

Answer (score 5):

#### GUI Solution

1. In nautilus, open up the selection dialog using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
2. Type `*.jpg` to select all images with the .jpg extension

[image]
[image]

3. Invert the selection using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> to select the ones without the .jpg extension (which is what you want).

[image]

4. Right click and choose `Move to trash` or just press the <kbd>delete</kbd> key.
   From here you can also do anything else you want - compress, cut, etc.

Comment: Didn't know nautilus could do that. notbad.png !

Comment: @Serg Nautilus is pretty powerful - for those of us who are not terminal wizards.

Answer (score 2):

Using `bash`, non-recursively:

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob
rm img.jpg+(?)
```

If you only have digits at the end:

```
rm img.jpg+([0-9])
```

Recursively:

```
shopt -s globstar extglob nullglob
rm **/img.jpg+(?)
```

In case of only digits at the end:

```
rm **/img.jpg+([0-9])
```

Here we have used a few shell options:

- `extglob` will enable us to match extended glob patterns e.g. `+(?)` will match one or more occurrences of any character. This should be enabled in a interactive shell by default.
- `nullglob` will result in a null string if no match is found
- `globstar` will enable us to search recursively using `**`